# How to tame massive tiled rasters in leaflet webmap

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, tiles

I have a project that has grown beyond it's initial scope.   I have multiple large rasters tiled in a leaflet webmap.   They were tiled using gdal2tiles.py which produced ~500,000 tiles per raster.

Now I would like to migrate to another server and it's completely unwieldy.   Could a geoserver handle these massive rasters?   What other options do I have to serve large rasters in a leaflet webmap?

Comment: how big are the original rasters? GeoServer handles Tb with no issues.

Comment: each .tif is <500MB.

Comment: If the data does not change another option could be wrapping the tiles in an mbtile file, then serving them with a simple mbtiles-server, or just push them as is to a cdn. If they do change then geoserver.

Comment: There is no change... I'll look into wrapping the tiles in an mbtile file.